# Django - Show date and time of appointment

Tags: django, list, datetime, django-queryset

I'm currently showing all dates that appointments are not booked.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

num_days = 5
start_date = date.today()
timeframe = [start_date + timedelta(days=d) for d in range(num_days)]
exclude = list(Appointment.objects.values_list("start_appointment__date", flat=True).distinct())

set(timeframe) - set(exclude)
```

Model of appointments

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seat = models.ForeignKey(Seat, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    work = models.ManyToManyField(Therapy, related_name='work', verbose_name=_('Work'), blank=True)
    start_appointment = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
    end_appointment = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
```

For example i have appointments booked for:

```
[datetime.date(2021, 12, 8), datetime.date(2021, 12, 7), datetime.date(2021, 12, 7), datetime.date(2021, 12, 7)]
```

And the dates not booked:

```
{datetime.date(2021, 12, 10), datetime.date(2021, 12, 9), datetime.date(2021, 12, 11)}
```

I would like to show also the available times for the not booked dates with a time interval between 11:00AM to 21:00PM:.

Is that possible with the current implementation? If yes how can i achieve that? If not could you please suggest an alternative way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to show available times, i suggest to separate your response by dates, so if you have one day like datetime(2021, 12, 8) and you want to show times between 11AM and 21PM you can use something like:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, time

    
date_of_reference = datetime(2021, 12, 8, 0, 0) #your the object of database
initial_time = datetime.combine(date_of_reference.date(), time(11, 0))
final_time = datetime.combine(date_of_reference.date(), time(21,0))

reserved_times = [datetime(2021, 12, 8, 11, 0), datetime(2021, 12, 8, 15, 0)] #reserved_times from database here

hours_between = [datetime.combine(date_of_reference.date(), time(hour + initial_time.hour, 0)) for hour in range(((final_time - initial_time).seconds // 3600) + 1)]
avaliable_hours = [hour for hour in hours_between if hour not in reserved_times]
```

In your code will be something like

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from .models import Appointment


# views
def check_available_hours(request):
    day_request = request.GET.get('day','') #day in format yyyy-MM-dd
    date_of_reference = datetime.strptime(day_request, "%Y-%m-%d")
    initial_date_time = date_of_reference
    final_date_time = date_of_reference + timedelta(hours=23)
    appointments_of_day = Appointment.objects.filter(
        start_appointment__gte=initial_date_time,
        start_appointment__lte=final_date_time
    )
    reserved_times = [
    appointment.start_appointment + timedelta(minutes=10*i) for appointment in appointments_of_day for i in range((appointment.end_appointment - appointment.start_appointment).seconds//600)]
    # same as above but more undestandeble
# for appointment in appointments_of_day:
#     for i in range((appointment.end_appointment - appointment.start_appointment)//600):
#         reserved_times.append(appointment.start_appointment + timedelta(minutes=10*i))
    hours_between = [initial_date_time + timedelta(minutes=10*i) for i in range(((final_date_time - initial_date_time).seconds // 600) + 1)]
avaliable_hours = [hour.time() for hour in hours_between if hour not in reserved_times]
    
    return render(request, "name_template.html", {"hours": avaliable_hours})
```

If your appointments do not have a duration of a multiple of 10, you have to change the code to controll for every minute instead of 10 minutes as in the example above

Comment: Thank you for help. Is very close to what i want. If you could please help me to write based on my models i would highly appreciate it! Thank you once more.

Comment: @paniklas I edited my answer, if you have any problems if it i will be glad to reply you

Comment: Thank you for replying based on my models. I tried the code you provide me and here the results. I changed `day_request` to `day_request = date.today()
    day_request1 = str(day_request)` when i print i got `2021-12-08` and
`2021-12-08 00:00:00`. Then i get ìnitial_date_time 2021-12-08 00:00:00` and
`final_date_time 2021-12-08 23:00:00`. Then i correctly getting booked appointments `<QuerySet [<Appointment: johnsmall@gmail.com>, <Appointment: jimbig@gmail.com>]>`. However the reserved_times does not return anything. Any ideas?